# Java API for squid-like filesystem hierarchical data-structure

Tags: java, data-structures, filesystems, squid

Are there any java systems (API) where "documents" (binary content) may be submitted and stored in a filesystem in a hierarchical structure, much like squid (web proxy) stores cached resources?

Comment: Why do you need a Java API for this? How is it different from using the OS to save binary files in the (hierarchical) filesystem?

Comment: It would be a time-saver to use an existing/tested API than to make one myself. An API that you will invoke a "void submit(OutputStream)" and the resource will end up in the filesystem in hex_hex/hex_hex/hex_hex_hex_hex where all hexes are computed and created transparently. Obviously a complementary "InputStream retrieve(String hex)" should exist.

Comment: 1. Where is the hierarchical aspect of the storage you are looking for? 2. where would the hex string components come from (I suppose you are referring to the hexadecimal representation of some unique-per-instance ID)? 3. Wouldn't a trivial ID->UNC conversion process, plus automatic subdirectory creation functionality, do the job? Or is that the functionality that the "API" should deliver?

Answer (score 0):

[Is Apache's JackRabbit what you're after?](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)